# Cannot find module 'umask'

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. Today I tried to create a new project using ionic. When I tried adding android platform to my app using this command `ionic platform add android` am getting the below error:

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
    module.js:327
        throw err;
        ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'umask'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jeffrey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
    dova\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\umask.js:1:75)
```

nodejs Version:
5.4.1
Please anyone resolve this error as soon as possible.

Comment: did you cd into the new project folder before adding the platform?

Comment: Yes I did @HishamAbdel-Hafez

Comment: if you are on a mac or a linux, can you try "sudo ionic platform add android"

Comment: NO I am using Windows 8.1@HishamAbdel-Hafez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try uninstalling and reinstalling cordova using npm:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@latest
```